# Is it correct to say "copious amount of"?

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following are correct?

1. I drink copious coffee
2. I drink copious amounts of coffee

I frequently hear people say #2 but it doesn't sound right to me (though "a myriad of X" doesn't either).

Comment: I think this may be a difference of dialects. *Copious* before a mass noun, like *copious rain*, sounds wrong to me—I feel it should be *copious amounts of rain*. But lots of people on the web say *copious rain*.

Comment: I'd go for number 2 as well.

Comment: Me too. Though I might also say 'I drink a copious amount of coffee'

Comment: @WS2: Google NGrams confirms my gut feel that singular *a copious amount* hasn't experienced the [remarkable rise in popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+copious+amount%2Ccopious+amounts&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20copious%20amount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopious%20amounts%3B%2Cc0) of the plural form in recent decades.

Comment: One reason I think that "copious coffee" is better to my ear is that "copious amount" is near-redundant, as is "copious amounts." _Copious_ already tells you you're talking about an amount. You could just as easily say "a large amount" as "a copious amount."

Comment: @kuzzooroo: It may sound *logical* to you, but the usage patterns show conclusively that *hasn't* significantly influenced other speakers/writers. They've all but abandoned *copious* in general, but for the last several decades, the specific form ***copious amounts*** has been rising dramatically. It doesn't make sense to say something sounds "better to your ear" if everyone else is using a different form. In matters of idiomatic usage, surely what sounds "better" is *what most people actually say*, not what some people think they *should* say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peter's comment intrigued me, since I feel much the same way. Compare the decline of *copious*...

[image]

...with the recent upswing for *copious amounts*...

[image]

There are a few other collocations that have remained relatively stable over the past century or more, but offhand I can only think of [*copious **hair***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copious%20hair&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1;,copious%20hair;,c0) and [*copious **notes***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copious%20notes&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1;,copious%20notes;,c0). OED says of the *plentiful, abundant* sense...

> Now chiefly used with nouns expressing production or supply, or in reference to quantity produced; with names of material substances, it is obs. or arch., but is used of literary materials.

I admit I'm not quite sure what they mean there, but I know I wouldn't say I *drink copious tea*, or that Britain is currently *experiencing copious rain* (both *true* - they just don't sound *right* to me).

See my comment (#4) to the question itself for a link showing the equally intriguing fact that singular *a copious amount* was once actually *more* common than the current favourite pluralised version. So we can't say that *copious amounts* is a "fixed phrase/frozen form", because historically it was never a front-runner anyway. I really don't know why it's so popular today.

Comment: One more collocation, which I've been a little hesitant to post: if you drink enough water the day before a track meet, your urine will be "clear and copious."

Comment: @kuzzooroo: I'm not saying you won't find *any* current instances of that one, but [according to Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clear+and+copious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclear%20and%20copious%3B%2Cc0), the decline of *that* particular collocation has been even more dramatic than that of the word "copious" overall. Whereas if you click through my links for ***hair*** and ***notes***, you'll see that they've held up pretty steady.

Comment: We can certainly say that _copious amounts_ is a fixed phrase, though perhaps not quite that it’s a frozen form. The fact that it has recently gained in popularity doesn’t change the fact that it’s a fixed phrase.

Answer (score 1):

*Copious* means abundant... when used with *amount* it shows emphasis on the abundance of the quantity implied... just like *scarce amount* would be an emphasis on the lack of amount implied... it helps to measure amount.

Answer (score -1):

Amount of is right.

Would you say 'there is large amount of rain and thunder', or 'there is a large rain and thunder'?

The reader might infer 'amount of', but why should they have to?

Yes, when it's more obvious, it seems less necessary to use 'amount of', but not wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. Please take the [guided tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about answering and asking questions here. Your answer doesn't hit the mark here because it just expresses an opinion. We need answers backed by some sort of reference, citation or link. Also, the question isn't really worth answering (in my opinion) because it doesn't satisfy the requirements and is very likely to be closed.